# Symengine serialization

Tags: python, c++, serialization, pickle, symbolic-math

Im working on a project where i need to create a an array of functions that are combinations of partial derivatives of other functions in the array. These functions needs to be lambdified, and then evaluated continuously, as quick as possible as it is part of a real-time simulator. I’ve experimented using symengine in c++ and python and sympy in python. I need to use the functions in c++ and i have managed to make them using symengine, but they get quite hairy and slow to evaluate, and i understand there is no simplify function in symengine. I’ve noticed that functions can be evaluated much quicker if they have been simplified using sympy.simplify() before being lambdified.(this also work with symengine functions i python). Is there a way to serialize and store the arrays of functions(symbolic or lamdified) from python and load them in c++? Or is there some other symbolic math library for c++? Or is there a way to simplify symengine functions in c++?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please stick with a language and ask a specific question.  Without actual code, it's difficult to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: One way to go about this is to use Sympy to generate the functions and then export C++ code for them; I assume that's possible in Sympy, although if there isn't a specific C/C++ export, there is probably a function to print stuff in a form which can be used as input, and that will be close enough since Python math syntax is not too different from C/C++. The one exception might be exponentiation, you might need to substitute `pow(x, y)` for `x**y` or something like that. Probably you'll get a more informative response on a Sympy-specific forum. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Thanks @RobertDodier. I ended up doing this

Answer (score 0):

In python you can save the bytes

```
expr.__reduce__()[1][0]
```

and then load that in C++

```
Basic::loads(str)
```

Note that this is fragile and you need to use the same symengine version for both python and C++